# Config default Git branch name

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm working with a repo which has a specific 'folder' structure. I must create features in branches named `feature/myBranchName`, fix bugs in branches named `bugfix/myBranchName` etc.

So, the question: Can I somehow specify a default branch name using SourceTree  or `git` itself? I want to mask every new branch name like `feature/*`

Ok, let's explain more clearly:

1. I'm opening SourceTree.
2. I'm pushing the button 'branch'.
3. In the branch window I have a textfield where I specify the branch name.
4. I want masked input in this textfield with mask `topic/*` or something like that.

Comment: Can you give an example of what behavior you want?  It's not clear to me from your question...

Comment: @larsks, I updated quiestion. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible using the [Git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) branching model, both from command line and also through SourceTree.

Once you have [installed the Git-flow command line tools](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/Installation), you can simply call

```
git flow init
```

in your local repository and it will allow you to define the branch names you have mentioned.

You can do the same in SourceTree by pressing the "Git Flow" button in the toolbar:

[image: SourceTree]

More details [here](http://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2012/08/01/smart-branching-with-sourcetree-and-git-flow/)

Comment: Thnx. It's exactly what i need.